# Melt reshape 2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, reshape

I need help to `melt` my data set such that I can plot the average resale price of each region using line graphs in `ggplot2` which I intend to put into a `shiny` app

Here's an example of my data set.

```
town           flat_model resale_price year region
1 ANG MO KIO   MODEL A      345000     2007 North_East
2 BISHAN       MODEL A      336000     2009 Central
3 SEMBAWANG    MODEL A      385000     2010 North
```

Here's the graph which I intend to make. I made this using Tableau
[image: picture]

I just need help with melting the data set so that I can carry on.
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using `dplyr::gather()` to achieve this. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you dont need to `melt` your data, it's already in long format (one variable per column, one observation per row).

If you want an average resale price for each region and year, you want to `group_by` and `summarize`, something along the lines of:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, region) %>% 
  summarize(mean_price = mean(resale_price))
```

Using this as example data, I get something which would allow you to plot the regional annual means.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  'year' = c(1,1,2,2,2),
  'region' = c('A','B','A','B','B'),
  'resale_price' = c(4,7,5,9,8))
```